# return from firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

My function :

```
export async function getDataUser() {

    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('UsersList');
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let dataUser;

    if (user) {                      //EDITED
        await usersRef.child(user.uid).once('value').then((snapshot) => {

            dataUser = snapshot;
        })
    }
    console.log("dataUser")
    console.log(dataUser)
    return dataUser;
}
```

then in another component  :

```
console.log("result")
console.log(getDataUser())
```

I would like that my function return snapshot but here is my result :

result

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

dataUser

```
Object {
  "age": "55",
  "email": "test@test.fr",
  "sexe": "homme",
}
```

i don't know why my result is wrong, my return should send the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code and what I found working was this:

When you return the promise value, you could attach a `.then()` callback and after check the result in that callback. Like this:

```
export async function getDataUser() {

    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('UsersList');
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let dataUser;

    if (user) {
        return await usersRef.child(user.uid).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            return dataUser = snapshot; // or return dataUser = snapshot.val();
        })
    }        
}
```

After to display:

```
getDataUser().then((result)=>{
console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: result 
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
} and dataUser = null,  my dataUser are already fine

Comment: @ThibautChazalon can you show how your database is populated?

Comment: https://ibb.co/kSeFJ0 But did you notice that my dataUser is already fine?

Comment: @ThibautChazalon I edited my solution. Hope this helps, if it still doesn't work we can continue looking. :)

Comment: Fine it's work, it was a simple question but will help me a lot for future, Thank you

Comment: @ThibautChazalon Great! Can you put this answer on solved. :)

Answer (score 2):

`on()` doesn't return a promise.  It sets up a persistent listener that continues to receive updates until you call `off()`.  If you want to fetch data a single time and receive a promise when the data is ready, use [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) instead.